# Applying function objects with lambda functions. ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Tags: python, pandas

Context I'm trying to apply several functions from a list of function objects into a specific dataframe column, however, I keep getting this error "ValueError: Columns must be same length as key"

```
possible_message_names = ['x','y','z']
path_of_the_directory= r'{}'.format(path_of_the_directory)
processing_list = [remove_whitespace,convert_to_unicode]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_of_the_directory):
    print("Normalizing the files in the directory: {}".format(root))
    for individual_file in tqdm(files):
        dataframe = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(os.path.join(root, individual_file)))
        for possible_column_name in possible_message_names:
            if possible_column_name in dataframe.columns:
                
                dataframe[possible_column_name] = dataframe[possible_column_name].apply(lambda text: method(text) if type(text) == str else text for method in processing_list )
        dataframe.to_excel('{}\\normalized_{}'.format(root,individual_file), index=False)
```

Any help is very welcome

P.S. I'm trying to normalize unicode (hence the convert_to_unicode function in the list)

EDIT: I notice that doing

```
dataframe[possible_column_name].apply(lambda text: method(text) if type(text) == str else next for method in processing_list )
```

instead of

```
dataframe[possible_column_name] = dataframe[possible_column_name].apply(lambda text: method(text) if type(text) == str else next for method in processing_list )
```

solves this error, but the functions aren't being applied this way...

Something like this seems to work:

```
for method in processing_list : #iterates over the methods added by the user in the pipeline and applies to the column to be cleaned
    if callable(method): #if the method is a function object
        dataframe[possible_column_name ] = dataframe[possible_column_name ].apply(method)
```

Comment: I suspect what you really should be using is `reduce()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping over the methods in the `apply` argument, loop over them in the script and then apply the method to all rows.

This will accumulate all the modifications rather than returning a generator of calls on the original text.

```
        for possible_column_name in possible_message_names:
            if possible_column_name in dataframe.columns:
                for method in processing_list:
                    dataframe[possible_column_name] = dataframe[possible_column_name].apply(lambda text: method(text) if type(text) == str else text)
```